# I want to write to the own i2c library at stm32f407 . How to define the input and output legs

Tags: i2c, stm32f4discovery

I want to write to the own i2c library  at stm32f407 . I have to use both input and output at same pin(legs). Example SDA:PD15, SCL:PD14. PD15 and pd14 are both input and output. how can defined this input,output in stm32f407

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean a software I<sup>2</sup>C driver, toggling the bits one at a time (bit-banging), because the on-chip I<sup>2</sup>C controllers can't use `PD14` or `PD15`.

Use *General purpose output mode* in `GPIOD->MODER` and *Output [open-drain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_drain)* in `GPIOD->OTYPER`.

```
GPIOD->MODER = (GPIOD->MODER & ~(GPIO_MODER_MODER14 | GPIO_MODER_MODER15)) | GPIO_MODER_MODER14_0 | GPIO_MODER_MODER15_0;
GPIOD->OTYPER |= GPIO_OTYPER_OT_14 | GPIO_OTYPER_OT_15;
```